Flutter Undefined name 'WidgetStateProperty'
I am trying to run this code example https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_adaptive_scaffold/example
but the code does not compile showing Undefined name 'WidgetStateProperty'.
Have tried restarting VS Code and flutter clean/get - not helpful.
Also, tried to copy WidgetStateProperty class into my project, but then I got WidgetState is not a type.
I searched and found this issue https://github.com/hiddify/hiddify-next/issues/946 which seems to be somehow similar but not helpful.
I am on Windows using the latest versions of VS Code, Dart and Flutter
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4412], locale en-US)
Any ideas?

Can you add your code snippet where you tried this?

there is a link to code above

Try MaterialStateProperty instead.

So, I faced the same problem while using package
the simple solution was to replace all the
...
WidgetStateProperty
...

by
...
MaterialStateProperty
...

=================================================
also on a side note, if you have
WidgetState

replace it with
MaterialState

EDIT: I faced this issue because the package had a typo that led me to this error.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for your input. It was a typo in the package itself when I faced it.

no, no, no, check MaterialStateProperty - it clearly says: "This feature was deprecated after v3.19.0-0.3.pre. Use WidgetStateProperty instead." - the original poster uses 3.22 so he should use WidgetStateProperty - the errors he gets are caused by some setup errors

Upgrading flutter SDK to 3.22 fixed the problem for me

solved by doing as suggested already here.
5
So, I faced the same problem while using package
the simple solution was to replace all the
...
WidgetStateProperty
...
by
...
MaterialStateProperty
...

This same answer was added here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78649651/12649675, if you have something to add, you could comment on the answer or possibly upvote if it resolves the issue for you.

I ran Debug - and got a message that errors exist in the project do you like to debug anyway - Yes, then the project is properly built and errors disappear.

you are auto responding you for a problem that is very specific to you. Any problems from my side when I use the code example

@ElLocoCocoLoco I have been using Flutter for about one year and this has happened to me first time.  The problem is very specific but the solution is kinda can be common.
